# Enums aligned in columns with the Eclipse formatter

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

The goal I am trying to achieve is to align enum definitions in columns when specifying the value of the enumerator. Please note that I only want my enumerations in columns, not my variable definitions.

```
enum class MY_ENUM {
  A   = 1,
  BB  = 2,
  CCC = 3
};
```

I am using STM-STUDIO, an Eclipse derive IDE for embedded targets to program C/C++. I have used the normal Eclipse formatter to configure my other style requirements but I am unable to find a way to do this.

Comment: Even if a lot in the CDT editor is customizable, I'm afraid, this is not. I'm sure you went through all pages of the formatting preferences, didn't you?

Comment: @thebusybee Yes I did. I was hoping for maybe a setting not in the GUI but in the formatter config file it self. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Well, now we are diving into the _real stuff_. Since Eclipse and its CDT are open source, it "just" takes some time to find out. ;-) Unfortunately my free time is heavily limited.